# Working on Array inside Struct , with Assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-studio-2015

Im trying to check the even numbers from an array inside a struct, but i dont think i wrote something right. When debugging, (i.e. count = 3 v[] = {1,2,4}), after it reaches " cmp eax,[ebp+12] and je outt; " , it goes to outt:  and thats it.

s is supposed to keep the sum of all even numbers, eax inside int suma(test *) is index for array, and edx keeps the sum before moving it in s

what am i doing wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test {

int v[10];
short count;

};

test a;
int s = 6;

int suma(test *)
{
_asm {
    mov eax, 0;                 // i for counting inside array
    mov edx, 0;                 // sum of even elements
    mov ebx, [ebp + 8];         // array v adress


loop:
    cmp eax, [ebp + 12];
    je outt;

    mov ecx, [ebx + 4 * eax];
    inc eax;

    mov edi, ecx
    and ecx, 1;
    cmp ecx, 1;
    je loop;
    add edx, edi;
    jmp loop;


outt:
    mov eax, edx;
}

return s;

}


int main()
{

cin >> a.count;
for (int i = 0; i < a.count; i++)
    cin >> a.v[i];

_asm {

    LEA eax, a
    push eax;
    call suma;
    add esp, 4;
    mov s, eax;
}

cout << s;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you are using assembly?

Comment: `[ebp+8]` holds the address of `test` (as per the prototype). So to get the count you need `[ebx+40]` not `[ebp+12]` which would work if you passed the `count` as a separate argument. Also, `count` is a `short` which is most probably a 16 bit integer. Either use it as such, or change it to `int` (recommended).

Comment: You seem to be using an assembly sledgehammer to optimize something that your compiler will do for you just fine.  Why not use `if(value & 0x01){ s++; }`

Comment: You should be aware that this will produce *extremely sub-optimal code*. Not only is the assembly code that you've actually written sub-optimal compared to what a compiler would generate, but the fact that you've used branches and calls inside the inline assembly blocks basically guarantee that the output will be abysmal. I leave this comment a lot, but if you're trying to learn how to program in assembly, inline assembly is *not* the way to do it. VS ships with Microsoft's assembler (MASM), and you should consider using it to write your entire program in assembly. Otherwise, write C in C!

Comment: Thank you. It's what im supposed to work with for future university test, that's why im trying to get it,but it's kind of not-so-well explained and whatever i find on the internet is either way to comprehensive, either not what i need.
Thank you. A lot.